# Particle Effects Disappear When Transitioning to a New SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene, skemitternode

I'm working on a game using Sprite Kit. I have a particle effect that runs when an object collides with another object; however, this particle effect seems to disappear when I add a transition to another SKScene. What's causing this disappearance, and how do I solve this issue?

Edit: By disappear I mean that it does not appear in the current scene when the scene is still transitioning with all the sprites still showing. It has a 2 second time interval, so shouldn't I be able to see it?

Here's the code for the particle effect and scene transition:

```
- (void)player:(SKSpriteNode *)player didCollideWithEnemy:(SKSpriteNode *)enemy {
    Enemy *monster = (Enemy *)enemy;
    if(!monster.isMoving){
        SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyParticle" ofType:@"sks"]];
        emitter.position = player.position;
        [self addChild: emitter];
        isAlive = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"Hit");
        CrowdedData *crowdedData = [CrowdedData sharedManager];
        crowdedData.score = score;
        [player removeFromParent];


        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:2];   
        GameOver *scene = [GameOver sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [self.view presentScene:scene transition:reveal];
    }

}
```

Comment: because the particles node is on one scene and you're replacing the scene with another. You wouldn't expect sprites from scene A to remain when presenting scene B either, right?

Comment: No, what I mean is that I have a fade transition and while the current scene is still fading (all the sprite are still showing on the scene), I'm expecting a particle effect but it just doesn't show. The particle effect is supposed to run right when the player is hit, and I do that before transitioning to the other scene.

Comment: you may want to keep the transitioning scenes animated, skview has a flag for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKTransition has two properties that are relevant to this:

```
[transition setPausesOutgoingScene:NO];
[transition setPausesIncomingScene:NO];
```

Both default to YES, causing either the outgoing in incoming scenes to be paused, which in turn pauses your emitter. For your purposes, setting the `pausesOutgoingScene` property to NO should be enough to fix this. More info in the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html